# PHP: Pass Arguments to function by Reference AND Value

Tags: php

Is there a way to have a function process parameters different, based on whether they are passed by variable or value?
E.g.: `foo("bar", $baz)` -> Both Parameters get processed different, not because of order, but because of passing method.

The problem I am running into is, that I somehow have to differentiate between the two, once they are passed into the function, they are indistinguishable from each other, as PHP functions are pass-by-value.

### Things I've tried:

1. Passing everything by reference (`function foo(...&$baz){}`)
   `foo($baz)` gets processed nicely, sadly `foo("bar")` runs into a fatal error.
2. Creating an Interface with explicit type declaration

   ```
   interface PassBy {
     public function foo(string $baz);
     public function foo(&$baz);
   }
   ```

Sounds good? Doesn't work. Fatal Error ("Cannot redeclare ...").

3. Searching for variable names in `$_GLOBALS` by value
   This fails miserably if **a)** the variable hasn't been instantiated yet or **b)** to variables happen to have the same value. Also it appears to be quite prone to mistakes.

### Context:

I am creating a class to create SQL-Querys using [fluent syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#PHP) (which means you can run a query like this: `$conn->newQuery("Test")->select([ ], ...)->execute()->close();` ).
Coming to the "SELECT"-Statement, I want to be able to either pass fixed values (e.g. SELECT **NAME** FROM ...) or variables for later evaluation (e.g. SELECT **$colName** FROM ...).

Comment: Avoid passing arguments by reference (and writing functions that accepts their arguments passed by reference). You don't need such functions.

Comment: If you want to pass something to a function for "later evaluation", you're looking for [a closure](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php), not a reference

Comment: *"I want to be able to either pass fixed values (e.g. SELECT **NAME** FROM ...) or variables for later evaluation (e.g. SELECT **$colName** FROM ...)"* -- Why do you thing `$colName` is evaluated later? Anyway, the idea can be implemented using a class that encapsulates the value or a reference to it or the name of the variable to be evaluated later (f.e. in the `__toString()` method of the class).

Comment: I don't get your problem... If you define your function like `function myFunc($test) { ...}` they you can call it either by `myFunc("myFixedValue");` or `myFunc($colName)` and it will perfectly work, simply insert the `$test` var into your query....

Comment: In the example you gave "SELECT $colName FROM"...why do you need it to be passed by reference? Are you planning to alter the value of $colname and then re-use it in some later code outside that function? That's really the only reason to pass it by reference. Have you misunderstood what pass by reference really means? You can still pass _variables_ by value, not just hard-coded values. Also the example doesn't entirely make sense anyway - if you pass "SELECT $colName FROM" to the function then $colname's value will be interpolated into the string and the _whole string_ is passed to the function

Comment: @axiac I generally agree; However, since I have to (should) bind variables later (PDO::prepare) I would need to use it for this approach. (I think...!) But I will take that advice and try to come up with another solution, thank you!

"Why do you think $colName is..." The point of this class is to build a query and then be able to execute it at later times (with different values in the variables). That requires a "placeholder". The __toString() is a rather interesting idea, I have not considered that yet - and will take a look at it! :)

Comment: It looks like a legitimate use case for using references, indeed. In general, the arguments passed by reference are a source of bugs and confusion because there is no sign in the code that calls such a function that the function might modify the value of a variable passed to it as argument. It's better when the functions `return` values instead of changing the values of the variables passed to them as arguments. PHP provides a lot of such functions (and we must live with that) but this is a slightly different case; the **purpose** of these functions **is** to modify their arguments.

Comment: @Twinfriends The query is build inside that function, dynamically, I need a method to differantiate between inserting a variable into the query (e.g. `SELECT $col FROM ...`) to assign a value to later, just before execution, and inserting a fixed value (e.g. `SELECT "NAME" FROM ...`) right away.

Comment: @ADyson I do not pass the whole `SELECT $colName FROM ...`, but only `$colName`. That may be a fixed string, which would evaluate the query to `SELECT "NAME" ...` or it may be a variable, that should only function as a placeholder to fill with a value at a later point. As such I have to somehow pass the name of the variable that is intended to use into the function, so I can then insert it into the query (which I generate inside the function/method.)
I am sorry, if I did not make that clear, your answer is much appreciated! :)

Comment: @axiac Thank you for your input. I will try to find a way around that, possibly without using pass-by-reference, as the whole point of this project is to make the code of DB-Operations more readeable and maintainable!

Comment: ok so..."I have to somehow pass the name of the variable that is intended to use into the function, so I can then insert it into the query"...so I assume this variable is a global then, which the function can read from by itself? Otherwise I don't see how passing the _name_ of a variable would be much use. Perhaps you can give us a clearer, more detailed example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ADyson
Thou shall receive! (Example for a single entry, can of course easily extended to support multiple arguments)
`function query(...$columns) {
   return "SELECT $columns[0] FROM users";
}`  

Passing a value (`query("name");` ) will (and should) return `SELECT name FROM users`.  
However if you pass a variable (`query($col);` ) it **is supposed to** (and won't) return `SELECT $col FROM users`.

Comment: "it is supposed to (and won't) return SELECT $col FROM users"...I'm not sure, why would you think it would return that? If the value of $col is "XYZ" when you pass it in, then the value returned will be the string "SELECT XYZ FROM Users". When a variable is included in a double-quoted string like that, then at the moment the string is created, PHP gets the current value of the variable and makes it part of the string (assuming it's not an object or something else which is hard to string-ify).

Comment: It should also be noted that unless you are keeping strict control of what is in $col, and not leaving it in any way open to user input, then this code is at pretty high risk of SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @ADyson "I'm not sure, why..." I don't, this is simply the behaviour I desire - and trying to achieve with this. That is the point of all this. :D

And regarding the SQL-Injection Risk: Yes, the whole query is converted into a PDO prepared Statement before execution to prevent that. That is the reason why I need the variable name in the first place, otherwise I could let it execute "as-is" and watch as Bobby Tables ravages through my data.

Comment: " the whole query is converted into a PDO prepared Statement before execution to prevent that."...that won't prevent anything, because it only protects you using values you pass into the PDO prepared statement as parameters. Values you _already injected_, like this one, will go unnoticed. And table names can't be parameterised, either. The only protection you might have is if it refuses to prepare 2 queries in one, perhaps, this will depend on your PDO settings. And that protection won't catch all forms of injection.

Comment: anyway, to achieve your stated goal, is it maybe as simple as this: https://eval.in/1029693 ?

Comment: @ADyson I really appreciate the effort you put into this. I see the problem regarding SQL Injection - and will sanitize fixed input as well.
Sadly your eval.in runs into two problems: A) every fixed value (e.g. query("abc") ) would get evaluated into "SELECT $abc ..." as well,  and with a variable it set the name of the placeholder to the **value** of the variable - not to it's name. I am currently trying out some ideas, I will update you as soon as im done with them. (https://eval.in/1029709)

Comment: Yes my intention was that you would pass the eventual name of the variable as the input to the method. Thus avoid the impossible business of getting the name of the actual variable used - that makes no sense - the variable you use to pass a value into the function might be called $xyasdlkjhg, but _inside_ the function the name of that variable is _always_ $column. _Always_. Because that's what your function calls it. It neither knows nor cares what variable that value was in before. Even if you pass-by-reference you pass a _reference_ to the value's location in memory, not a variable name

Comment: i.e. you basically pass a pointer to the value, instead of a copy of the value. It's still nothing to do with variable names - they're just syntactical sugar to refer to locations in memory. The program doesn't actually give a monkey's about them, they're entirely for the coder's sanity - otherwise we'd all still be programming in sequences of 1s and 0s and pulling levers to set the bits. Asking to get the name of the variable used is impossible and a bit nonsensical anyway. My idea was to pass in a string which would eventually _become_ a variable name in the string constructed for output.

Comment: Regarding the fixed value issue, would this workaround be good enough for you? https://eval.in/1029721. I do it like that because, again, there is no way for the function to intrinsically know whether you passed in a variable or a hard-coded string - all it gets is a _value_, placed into the $column variable. Where that value came from is irrelevant to it.